# How to resolve 503.0 error in IIS container

Tags: iis, azure-web-app-service, containers, http-status-code-503, azure-appservice

I just started using IIS in a container on Azure App Service.

I get 503.0 errors on a windows container (IIS):

```
HTTP Error 503.0 - Service Unavailable
The service is unavailable.

Most likely causes:
- An invalid identity in the application pool could cause this error.
- The application pool is no longer running because of configuration or reaching application failure limits.
- The concurrent application request limit was reached.
```

Even after an App Service restart, the problem persists.
So I deleted and then recreated the service app.

I see these errors only on an environment with more load but not on a test env.

Do you have any idea to help me avoid these 503.0 errors?
Is it possible to stop one container among others in App Service?

Comment: A 503 Service Unavailable Error indicates that a web server is temporarily unable to handle a request, the error can occur for a number of reasons, i suggest you use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was ultimately due to out of memory. I increased the memory limit used by each container in the App Service (parameter: `WEBSITE_MEMORY_LIMIT_MB`).

I did not understand at the beginning why I was receiving the out-of-memory error despite the app service graphs showing use of 40%. This is because the node which hosts the Windows containers already consumes around 50% of the physical memory, but I think it lacks visibility on memory usage with Windows containers.

Support says:

> On Azure App Service Windows container we do not have memory analysis detector in Diagnose and solve problems blade.